# x86_64 - opcode map. Possible mistake?

Tags: x86-64, opcode

I am working on the intel opcode map for x86_64, *vol2, section B.2.1*

I have an issue with the `pop` instruction.

```
POP – Pop a Value from the Stack

wordregister
0101 0101 : 0100 000B : 1000 1111 : 11 000 reg16

qwordregister
0100 W00BS : 1000 1111 : 11 000 reg64

wordregister (alternate encoding)
0101 0101 : 0100 000B : 0101 1 reg16

qwordregister (alternate encoding)
0100 W00B : 0101 1 reg64

memory64
0100 W0XBS : 1000 1111 : mod 000 r/m

memory16
0101 0101 : 0100 00XB 1000 1111 : mod 000 r/m
```

The prefix `0101 0101` apparently used with wordregisters is really annoying me here, because I cannot find any use for it.

Even after submiting the command to `objcopy` or other disassembler, I never see it appearing.

```
0:  66 59                   pop    cx
2:  59                      pop    rcx
```

I can understand the `1000 1111 : 11 000 reg16` and `0100 000B : 0101 1 reg16` parts though.

So, what about that `0x55`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set the CPU to x86_64, a [disassembler](https://www.onlinedisassembler.com/odaweb/) gives you

```
55    push rbp
```

And a click on `55` in this [reference](http://ref.x86asm.net/coder64.html#x50) points to `push` as well.

The `pop` instructions have the bit 3 (4<sup>th</sup>) to `1`, the `push` have it at `0`, like in 0x55.

There is definitely a mistake in the documentation, as the CPU instructions coding logic and other elements available on the Net clearly show 0x55 as being a push operation.

Comment: So you concur that it is a mistake in the doc?

Comment: Yes, it seems to be the case. Assembly language docs are probably the most error prone ones, due to the low readability of machine code and even instructions (unlike C for instance, which is however said to be close to the system/machine/assembly). There is however some logic at the binary level that helps to catch such mistakes (like bit 3 in this case).

Comment: Absolutely. There are so many other errors in that doc.. I will report to Intel I guess.